# i cant add toast in libgdx

Tags: interface, libgdx, toast

im trying to create toast by call it with interface
the interface works fine it just that when i try to make a toast with it, it crashes

in Android Launcher

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements Interface {    
 public void tost() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "wrong num",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}
```

in gameclass

```
   interface Interface{void tost();}
    public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
        final private Interface interface;
        public MyGdxGame(Interface interface){this.interface=interface;}
     public void render() {interface.tost}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android toasts must be performed on the Android UI thread. The game loop in LibGDX runs on the OpenGL thread, so you must post your method to the UI thread to safely run it, like this:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements Interface {    

    public void tost() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "wrong num",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            }
        });
    }

}
```